# Create Process default browser

Tags: c++, visual-c++

I'm currently using ShellExecute "open" to open a URL in the user's browser, but running into a bit of trouble in Win7 and Vista because the program runs elevated as a service.

I want to get thread id so ShellExecute is not possible to get thread id so i started using "CreateProcess" But i don't see any help on opening default browser whichever is it from CreateProcess.

Comment: `CreateProcess()` works differently. You cannot do it using this function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is another answer as you wanted. As far as you want it open as a new window. You can expand it for IE, opera, and so on...

```
DWORD size = MAX_PATH;
char buff[MAX_PATH];

int err = AssocQueryStringA(ASSOCF_INIT_IGNOREUNKNOWN, ASSOCSTR_EXECUTABLE, ".html", NULL, buff, &size);
STARTUPINFOA si;
PROCESS_INFORMATION pi;

ZeroMemory(&si, sizeof(si));
si.cb = sizeof(si);
ZeroMemory(&pi, sizeof(pi));

CStringA command_line;
CStringA target_url( "http://google.com/" );


if( strcmp( "chrome.exe", PathFindFileNameA(buff)) == 0 )
    command_line.Format("%s --new-window %s", buff, target_url);
else if( strcmp( "firefox.exe", PathFindFileNameA(buff)) == 0 )
    command_line.Format("%s -new-instance %s", buff, target_url);
else 
    command_line.Format("%s %s", buff, target_url);


if (!CreateProcessA(NULL,     // No module name (use command line)
    command_line.GetBuffer(),
    NULL,           // Process handle not inheritable
    NULL,           // Thread handle not inhberitable
    FALSE,          // Set handle inheritance to FALSE
    0,              // No creation flags
    NULL,           // Use parent's environment block
    NULL,           // Use parent's starting directory 
    &si,            // Pointer to STARTUPINFO structure
    &pi)           // Pointer to PROCESS_INFORMATION structure
)
{
    //... error handling
    return;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use other features of the [Shell API](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb773177(v=vs.85).aspx) to figure out which browser is the default.

For instance, you can ask the shell for the executable name associated with .html files using [AssocQueryString](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb773471(v=vs.85).aspx), and launch that via CreateProcess.

Answer (score 2):

Here you can open the URL with your default browser.

```
STARTUPINFOA si;
PROCESS_INFORMATION pi;

ZeroMemory(&si, sizeof(si));
si.cb = sizeof(si);
ZeroMemory(&pi, sizeof(pi));

CStringA command_line;
command_line.Format("cmd.exe /c start \"link\" \"%s\"", "http://www.google.com");

if (!CreateProcessA(NULL,     // No module name (use command line)
     command_line.GetBuffer(),
     NULL,           // Process handle not inheritable
     NULL,           // Thread handle not inhberitable
     FALSE,          // Set handle inheritance to FALSE
     NORMAL_PRIORITY_CLASS | CREATE_NO_WINDOW,              // No creation flags
     NULL,           // Use parent's environment block
     NULL,           // Use parent's starting directory 
     &si,            // Pointer to STARTUPINFO structure
     &pi)           // Pointer to PROCESS_INFORMATION structure
     )
{
     TRACE("CreateProcess failed (%d).\n", GetLastError());
     return;
}
```

Comment: You really fantastic. Well but i got a issue that it open as a tab rather than opening as new window, any solution?

Comment: In that case you need a bit of work. Cause you need to add a different command line arg for each browser. 
Go back to the solution with using AssocQueryString(). Check the default browser. If that's chrome, you should add --new-window for the sencond arg of CreateProcess(). If that's firefox, add -new-instance. Maybe you can add IE and others...

Comment: if (!CreateProcessA("C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe",     // No module name (use command line)
   "--new - window", ........ Give me ERROR CreateProcess failed: (2)

Comment: It might be an off topic, but I added it. Pleas vote if it helps you, thx.

Comment: Thanks very much. Well can you also tell me how would i change headers?

Comment: Oh, sorry. You might need to include <Shlwapi.h> for PathFindFileName(). If you still have some problem, just report me. pls.

Comment: I had already figured it and your code works very cool. But i have a doubt that how would i sent the headers for the browser i opened. Also will this code works in all pc?

Comment: What do you mean for "headers"? I believe that works in all Windows PC as far as they set chrome or firefox as their default browser.

Comment: Well i mean browser header like referrer, User agent etc etc. How would i edit them and add a something?

Comment: You can't set those HTTP headers. For example, referrer will be empty since you just opened the page, not be opened by other link or redirected. User agent will depend on your browser or your browser setting. Those headers will be set appropriately by the browser they use.

Comment: am sorry am going off topic but can you please help with me clearing cookies while closing the browser?

Comment: Well, It's not a programming topic, but you can delete cookie files from a specific folder for each browser. See http://www.catonmat.net/blog/clear-privacy-ie-firefox-opera-chrome-safari/ .