# C++ CreateprocessA Failed Error

Tags: c++, winapi, createprocess

I use this code but i get a failed error: 2 i know that means the file doesn't exist but no idea what am doing wrong.

```
DWORD size = 1024;
TCHAR buff[1024];

 int err = AssocQueryString(ASSOCF_INIT_IGNOREUNKNOWN, ASSOCSTR_EXECUTABLE, _T(".html"), NULL, buff, &size);

 STARTUPINFOA si;
 PROCESS_INFORMATION pi;

 ZeroMemory(&si, sizeof(si));
 si.cb = sizeof(si);
 ZeroMemory(&pi, sizeof(pi));
 LPCSTR BrowLoc = (LPCSTR)buff;

 if (!CreateProcessA(BrowLoc,     // No module name (use command line)
     NULL,
     NULL,           // Process handle not inheritable
     NULL,           // Thread handle not inhberitable
     FALSE,          // Set handle inheritance to FALSE
     0,              // No creation flags
     NULL,           // Use parent's environment block
     NULL,           // Use parent's starting directory 
     &si,            // Pointer to STARTUPINFO structure
     &pi)           // Pointer to PROCESS_INFORMATION structure
     )
 {
     printf("CreateProcess failed (%d).\n", GetLastError());
     getchar();
     return 0;
 }
```

Comment: What value does BrowLoc have?

Comment: Are you targeting Unicode? And why are you still using TCHAR? Do you really need to support Windows 98?

Comment: @NineBerry BrowLoc is having Location of the file to open. LPCSTR BrowLoc = (LPCSTR)buff;

Comment: @DavidHeffernan Not really Windows 98. Any other than am doing?

Comment: So if you won't support Windows 98, why are you using TCHAR? I know the answer. It's a rhetorical question. I'm trying to get you to question you approach instead of relying on copy/paste programming. You use TCHAR because you are copying code from elsewhere. But you need to ask yourself **why**? Judging from the comments to the answers you don't really care about the why and just want some code that you don't need to understand. That approach will condemn you to asking this question over and over again.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan I know you got me and can you help me with how can i passthe url to CreateProcess?

Comment: This question has been answered it seems

Comment: @DavidHeffernan you have to admit that Windows98 and its friends are still exists, for hobbyist, shcools or others. using TCHAR is in any way a bad habit or practice.

Comment: @milyevo If you need to target NT and 98 then go ahead and use TCHAR. Otherwise it's a very bad idea. Hobbyists won't care about Win98. Which schools will?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess you are using unicode. In that case, force using multi-byte character for AssocQueryString().

Use the code below for the first 3 lines.

```
DWORD size = 1024;
char buff[1024];

 int err = AssocQueryStringA(ASSOCF_INIT_IGNOREUNKNOWN, ASSOCSTR_EXECUTABLE, ".html", NULL, buff, &size);
```

Comment: argument of type "char *" is incompatible with parameter of type "LPWSTR".




When i use char buff[1024];

Comment: Did you use whole 3 lines I attached? 
The error will occur if you didn't replace the third line I attached.

Comment: I mean, use 'char' instead of 'TCHAR', use 'AssocQueryStringA' instead of 'AssocQueryString' and remove '_T()' macro for ".html".

Comment: Thanks a lot it worked. i removed converting code and Just used your code and buff in as file name. Saved me. Thanks.

Comment: Can you tell me how do i pass the Url on to createprocess?

Comment: Just add the URL string as an arg of the process. Try this. **CStringA command_line; command_line.Format("%s %s", buff, "google.com/"); CreateProcessA(NULL, command_line.GetBuffer(), ...);**
However, it may not work for all of the browser. So I recommend you to use other way. See the answer on your another question.

Comment: Can you post the link of answer on another question please?

Comment: I believe that's your question. I added another answer. ;) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35100729/create-process-default-browser